# PHP not creating $_SESSION variable on session_start();

Tags: php, apache, session

I have 3 pages in my set up here:

login.php: The login page that contains the username and password fields which submits to

checklogin.php: Which checks to see if the credentials are right which redirects to

login_successful.php: Which displays the user's name

login.php starts with

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <?php
        include 'content.php';
        echo $head;
    ?>
</head>
```

Which should initialize a global $_SESSION variable right?

checklogin.php has some code which looks like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
{
    /* Access denied */
    echo 'Sorry, your username or password was incorrect!';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    /* Log user in */
    header("location:login_successful.php");
}
```

login_successful.php looks like this:

```
<div id="title" style="margin:5px">
    <h2>Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately when I go through the login procedure and get to login_successful.php, I get this error "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\login_successful.php on line 15" even though I clearly started a session in login.php.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Did you include *session_start();* in every script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` at the top of *each* of your scripts

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that it is supposed to be called once globally.

Comment: Because http is stateless, each web request effectively starts php, runs, then shuts down - so you need to call it each time. If this answer solves the problem, please mark it as accepted using the big tick to the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember session_start() in checklogin.php